# Function object has no attribute yet this is a prebuilt scipy function

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to complete an assignment that requires me to create a histogram of a poisson distribution. I am attempting to use scipy's poisson functions, specifically poisson.rmv() to generate the distribution. Yet I am unable to use this function and keep getting the message function' object has no attribute 'rvs' although I know there is one. What could be the problem?

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
x = poisson.rvs(mu=3, size=1000)
plt.hist(x, density=True, edgecolor='black')
```

Comment: Your code runs perfectly for me.  (After I imported plt, also).

Comment: do you use `poisson.rmv()` or `poisson.rvs()` in your code? The code you shared works very well.

Comment: Good catch!  I didn't notice that code uses `poisson.rvs`, but he asks about `poisson.rmv`, which doesn't exist.